# MSVC compiler error involving nested templates

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-errors, nested-class

The following code compiles with GCC 4.7 and clang 3.0, but not with MSVC 10:

```
template <typename X>
struct point
{
    template <typename Seq>
    struct point_iterator
    {
        template <typename T> 
        struct deref;

        template <typename Sq>
        struct deref<point_iterator<Sq> >
        {
        };
    };
};

int main()
{
    typedef point<int> point_t;
    typedef point_t::point_iterator<point_t> Iterator;
    Iterator::deref<Iterator> m;
}
```

The compiler error that MSVC gives is:

```
test.cpp
testcpp(21) : error C2079: 'm' uses undefined struct 'point<X>::point_iterator<Seq>::deref<T>'
        with
        [
            X=int,
            Seq=point_t
        ]
        and
        [
            T=Iterator
        ]
```

I think the type in question should be defined, since it should match the partial specialization of `deref`.

1. Is this valid code? If so, and rejecting it is a bug on MSVC's part, does anyone know whether the bug has already been reported?
2. If it's a bug, does anyone know of a workaround for it?

Comment: I tried adding `template<> struct Q<R<S<T> > >;` and MSVC8 rewarded me with an internal compiler error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that MSVC10 does not agree that you specialized the class. If you try this

```
    template <typename Sq>
    struct deref
    {
       typedef int basic;
    };

    template <typename Sq>
    struct deref<point_iterator<Sq> >
    {
       typedef int special;
    };
```

You'll find that `Iterator::deref<Iterator>::special` exists with gcc, but with MS only `basic` exists.

I do think your code is correct.

It's seems that only partial specialization is affected. Specializing on `int` works as expected.

Comment: In visual studio express 2010 neither of these work (note: in a context outside of the enclosing class, for example in main) work:`Iterator::deref<point_t::point_iterator<point_t> >::special qq; Iterator::deref<point_t::point_iterator<int> >::special qq;`

Answer (score 0):

**Your original code**

The following compiles on Visual C++ Express 2010 but generates the wrong answer:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename X>
struct point
{
    template <typename Seq>
    struct point_iterator
    {
        template <typename> 
        struct deref 
        {
                static const int value = 0;
        };

        template <typename Sq>
        struct deref< point_iterator<Sq> > 
        { 
                static const int value = 1; 
        };
    };
};

int main()
{
    typedef point<int> point_t;
    typedef point_t::point_iterator<point_t> Iterator;
    int v = Iterator::deref<Iterator>::value;
    std::cout << v << "\n"; // prints 1 on gcc 4.5.1, prints 0 on VC++ 2010
    return 0;
}
```

This explains the compile-error you got: VC++ tried to instantiate the primary `deref` template, which you didn't define. At this point it might seem that VC++ is in error and that gcc / clang are superior compilers.

**An intermediate "solution"**

However, moving the `point_iterator` and its nested `deref` to an outside namespace `detail` gives identical but wrong results for both gcc and VC++. Calling `detail::point_iterator::deref` gives what you want, but called the nested `point_iterator` inside `point` now gives wrong results for both gcc and VC++! So apparently, nested templates are hard on compilers in general.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace detail {
    template <typename Seq>
    struct point_iterator
    {
        template <typename> 
        struct deref 
        {
                static const int value = 0;
        };

        template <typename Sq>
        struct deref< point_iterator<Sq> > 
        { 
                static const int value = 1; 
        };
    };
}

template<typename X>
struct point
{
        template<typename Seq>
        struct point_iterator
        :
                public detail::point_iterator<Seq>
        {};
};

int main()
{
    typedef point<int> point_t;

    typedef point_t::point_iterator<point_t> Iterator1;
    int v1 = Iterator1::deref<Iterator1>::value;
    std::cout << v1 << "\n"; // prints 0 on both gcc 4.5.1 and VC++ 2010

    typedef detail::point_iterator<point_t> Iterator2;
    int v2 = Iterator2::deref<Iterator2>::value;
    std::cout << v2 << "\n"; // prints 1 on both gcc 4.5.1 and VC++ 2010

    return 0;
}
```

**The recommended approach**

There are also other issues with nested templates: you cannot explicitly specialize inner templates without also specializing the outer templates (ironically, VC++ does allow for this non-standard feature!). This can be solved by using dummy template parameters and partially specializing them (although VC++ will require suppression of spurious compiler warnings if you give this dummy template parameter a default value).

My recommendation therefore would be to untangle the entire nested template hierarchy that you got, and simply define 3 separate templates, and specialize them to your liking. This will produce the easiest code and doens't give any surprises.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename X>
struct point {};

template <typename Seq>
struct point_iterator {};

template <typename> 
struct deref 
{
        static const int value = 0;
};

template <typename Sq>
struct deref< point_iterator<Sq> > 
{ 
        static const int value = 1; 
};

int main()
{
    typedef point<int> point_t;
    typedef point_iterator<point_t> Iterator1;
    int v = deref<Iterator1>::value;
    std::cout << v << "\n"; // prints 1 on both gcc 4.5.1 and VC++ 2010

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The output for the second example is not wrong. The partial specialization of `deref` applies to `detail::point_iterator<...>` only, and the main template to everything else. When you instantiate it with `point::point_iterator<...>`, the main template is a better match because `point::point_iterator<...>` is not the same as `detail::point_iterator<...>` (it just derives from it). Specialization does not apply to derived types of the specialized types, only the specialized type itself.

Comment: As for "untangling" the nested templates, this is not always possible for all use cases. For example, if A is a template and B is a nested template inside A, then `A<T>::B<X>` and `A<U>::B<X>` are distinct types. Making B not nested would make them the same type, which may be undesirable. In general, avoiding language features because they're "hard" is misguided. The onus is on compilers to get them right.

Comment: The overall conclusion is that this is a bug on MSVC's part and should be fixed. I have reported the bug to Microsoft and they agree that it's a bug: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/46875a95-6c52-43e2-a0f6-c4d305206736

Comment: @HighCommander4 Tnx for your comments. Great to hear that MS agrees it's a bug on their part. I agree with you that avoiding hard features is not something to do per se. OTOH, I would rather simulate nested templates with `detailed` namespace and simple containment wherever I could just to avoid these very subtle bugs.

Comment: @HighCommander4 Just out of curiosity: wouldn't `template<typename X, typename dummy = void> struct B` and `B<X, A<U> >` be a simpler way to get a unique `B` depending on the "embedding" class `A<U>`?

Comment: Good point, that gets you a unique `B` for each "embedding" class without using nesting. There are other reasons why nesting is preferrable, though. For example, it avoids polluting the enclosing namespace with additional names. In my case, I was writing a macro that was meant to be used at class scope, and that expanded to the definition of a nested class (call it `B`). `B` contained its own nested class, call it `C`. The name `B` was requested by the user as one of the macro arguments, but the name `C` was an implementation detail. [continued below]

Comment: It was thus preferrable to hide `C` as a nested class within `B`. To work around this bug, however, I had to declare `C` at the same scope as `B`, and uglify its name to avoid conflicting with another declaration at the same scope in the client code. If the macro were meant to be used at namespace scope, I could have opened an implementation namespace to house `C`, but I couldn't do that at class scope.

Comment: @HighCommander4 OK, for such very advanced uses and users, I agree nested class templates are a legitimate tool. For the code example you gave though, I still believe that regular templates (hidden in `detail` namespaces if  clients don't need them) are better for 99% of the coders out there. E.g. if someone takes over a project and decides he needs an explicit specialization of a nested template within a non-specialized template, he needs to refactor anyway. In golf terms: it's like hitting driver from the fairway into the green. You can do it, but it's damn hard to pull it off!